# How To Read Currunt URL and get specific elements from it

Tags: php, url

I have the following URL creating dynamically "http://mxcounters.com/gorilla-crowd/?page_id=4994?company_id=11" i want to read company_id from it. as each time it will be changed coming from previous page:
I have tried as follows but its showing empty variable

```
   $company_id = $_GET['company_id'];
   echo $company_id;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it isn't formatted correctly: http://mxcounters.com/gorilla-crowd/?page_id=4994&company_id=11 ?

Comment: the url is wrong there, the Query String values has to be separated with & (ampersands), here in your case it is '?', so change it &(amp) and request with GET method

Comment: You will need to take a look at your rewriting rules that take care to call your script. Looks like something is wrong there.

Comment: Actually the first ?page_id=4994 is complete URL to my page and then ?company_id=11 is an argument. @Egg
i.e http://mxcounters.com/gorilla-crowd/?page_id=4994 = http://mxcounters.com/gorilla-crowd/company

Answer (score 1):

Your URL's query string is wrongly formatted. The query string parameters need to be separated by `&` (`&amp;` when URL encoded) not `?` as in your example. As a result `$_GET['company_id']` isn't getting set.

Your URL should look like:-

```
http://mxcounters.com/gorilla-crowd/?page_id=4994&amp;company_id=11
```

Then `$_GET['company_id']` should contain `11` as expected.

Comment: Actually the first ?page_id=4994 is complete URL to my page and then ?company_id=11 is an argument. @drmonkeyninja
i.e http://mxcounters.com/gorilla-crowd/?page_id=4994 = http://mxcounters.com/gorilla-crowd/company

Comment: You still can only have one query string in a URL. `mxcounters.com/gorilla-crowd/?page_id=4994` already has a query string (the bit after the `?`) so you need to append additional parameters using `&`. It will not work otherwise!

Comment: SO i have to change the URL structure? drmonkeyninja

Comment: Yes, if you want to pass multiple parameters like you appear to be.

Answer (score 0):

I got the ID with another method that's work in my case perfectly

```
 $rest = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $company_id = substr($rest, -2, 2);
```

I get the whole link in a variable and then get the last 2 characters from this string as above and worked fine